# DynamoDB | How to ADD a boolean value to existing object

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to `ADD` a boolean value to an existing DyanmoDB document. 
I use the DocumentClient (js sdk).

Please consider the following code:

```
let _documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
let updateExpression = {
          TableName: 'some_table',
          Key: {'project_id': 1234},
          UpdateExpression: 'ADD #completed :completed',
          ExpressionAttributeNames : {
            '#completed' : 'completed'
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':completed': false /* changing to non-boolean value works */
          }
        };
 _documentClient.update(updateExpression, (err, params) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return
    }
    console.log('done deal');
 });
```

Running above code results in the following error:

```
Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: BOOLEAN
```

Changing `:completed` to equal a non-boolean value works.

**Question:** How can I add a boolean value to an existing object using DocumentClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **SET** action instead of **ADD** as in: `SET #completed = :completed`.

The **ADD** action only supports number and set data types.

See [Update Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) for more details and examples.